# Calling methods of objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For some reason I'm having difficulty calling methods of an object I've created when the object is in an array.

```
var balls = new Array();

balls[0] = new ball(0);
balls[1] = new ball(1);
balls[2] = new ball(2);


function ball(index)
{
    this.index = index;

    this.draw = function() {
        _canvasContext.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, 30, 30);
    }
}
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    balls[i].draw();
```

For some reason the .draw method can no longer be accessed?  I'm certain I'm doing something wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can't help if we have no idea what a _ball_ is and no idea what _ball.draw()_ looks like. Other than that, your code looks fine.  You are calling _ball.draw()_ correctly inside your for loop.

Comment: @adeneo: The loop is fine. We do need to know more about `ball`, though.

Comment: Apologies. Added the function definition in.

Comment: Are you sure this code is everything? how does this.img get resolved? I dont see it assigned. Either you should have them assigned, or execute the draw method in another objects context?

Comment: Also, what error do you get? (In what way does your code not work as you expect?)

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'draw' of undefined, even though I did define the elements of the array in global scope.

Comment: Try `console.log(balls)` right above your `for` loop. I suspect it is not what you think it is.

Comment: yeah, be careful about the `var balls =` part, if this code is inside a function (onload or ready) when you define with the var keyword it wont be global, but local to the function. Its hard to determine with the code you have supplied.

Comment: @NathanWall Thank you very much nathan - the value of balls was being reset to 1 elsewhere in my code, hence the array values were undefined!

Comment: Learning to debug with Firebug (or the Chrome debugger) makes it super easy to troubleshoot issues like this.